# Let user input a simple text in edittext then let show in textview on more pages how to R.id string sharedpreferences

Tags: javascript, xml, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I am hoping someone can help me understand and use the shared preferences string in Android studio. I have a text view (on more pages) & edit text(in settings) ( and a button) i would like to let the user put Some text in a edit text and have the info stored in shared prefrences so it can be displayed in the textview section on all pages. How can i get this working? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the SharedPreferences is simply a file that you create, edit and get values from.
I will show you steps to clarify its meaning for you and help you implement it :

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button saveInputBtn;
    EditText userInputET;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    String userInput;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        saveInputBtn = findViewById(R.id.save_user_input);
        userInputET = findViewById(R.id.user_input);

        // 1) Affect an "onClickListener" to your button, that will inform your app when the user clicks on this button. 
        // The method saveTextAndLaunchSecondActivity() will only be launched if the button is clicked.
        saveInputBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveTextAndLaunchSecondActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    private void saveTextAndLaunchSecondActivity() {
        // 2) Get the input entered by the user inside your EditText
        String userInput = userInputET.getEditableText().toString();

        // 3) Create a file called sharedPrefName to stock values, that is "private" 
        // (so it cannot be accessed by other application than your)
        sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // 4) Create an "Editor", that will allow you to edit the SharedPrerences 
        // file you just create.
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();

        // 5) Use the Editor to put a String value inside the file. 
        // The SharedPreferences use a "key-value" system to store values,
        // below, "KEYNAME" is the key and userInput is the value that we
        // fetched inside the EditText 
        editor.putString("KEYNAME", userInput);
        editor.apply();

        // 6) Create a intent that specify you want to go on another Activity
        // and use the "startActivity" method with the created Intent inside
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Now that we have extracted the value from the EditText and stored it inside the SharedPreferences, plus launching the SecondActivity, we need to retrieve this userInput.

In the SecondActivity you can use this :

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    TextView secondActivity_TV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        secondActivity_TV = findViewById(R.id. TV_second_activity);

        // 7) Get the SharedPreferences file with its key : "sharedPrefName"
        sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // 8) Get the userInput that you stored inside those SP
        // The key has to match the one you created, the value "hey" is the 
        // default value = the value that the SharedPreferences will give 
        // you if the key does not match
        String userInputReceived = sharedPrefs.getString("KEYNAME","hey");

        // 9) And now you can assign it to your TextView
        secondActivity_TV.setText(userInputReceived);
    }
}
```

The SharedPreferences created in the FirstActivity can then be used in any other activities, as long as the key you create matches the one you use to get the value.
I really hope this will help you, let us know how it is going and if you have questions !